# Send List of IDs from List of Object From View to Controller C#

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a view with a list of objects as its model

```
@model List<Users>
```

Inside that view, I have a form and button to submit the form in ASP.NET Core MVC:

```
<input class="btn btn-success ml-2" style=" width: 100px;" 
       type="submit" value="@localizer["Save"]" />
```

I need another button to cancel form submission and redirect to another method but I need to pass the list of Users with redirection at cancel button

I tried

```
<a asp-controller="User" asp-action="cancel" asp-route-ids="@Model.Select(x => x.id);">Cancel</a>
```

but it didn't work, the list is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use asp-route-somekey to set the query, your target list name was recognized as value of the key "Ids",you could see the result as below:
[image]

[image]

If you do want to pass list to the query,you could try:

```
<a asp-controller="User" asp-action="Cancel" asp-all-route-data="@(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Ids[0]", "1" },{ "Ids[1]", "2" } })">Cancel</a>
```

The result:
[image]

However the length of url is limited, it may cause some errors

Comment: Thanks, It Worked With Your Solution, But I converted my list to dictionary not static as you explained